# How can I use rperl with perlbrew?

Tags: perl, rperl

I have this simple `rperl` program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use RPerl;
use strict;
use warnings;
our $VERSION = 0.001_000;

# [[[ CRITICS ]]]
## no critic qw(ProhibitUselessNoCritic ProhibitMagicNumbers RequireCheckedSyscalls)  # USER DEFAULT 1: allow numeric values & print operator
## no critic qw(RequireInterpolationOfMetachars)  # USER DEFAULT 2: allow single-quoted control characters & sigils
## no critic qw(ProhibitInterpolationOfLiterals) # USER DEFAULT 3: allow anything

print 'Hello Perl', "\n";
```

See Exercise 1 in [Learning RPerl](http://rperl.org/learning/#CHAPTER_1%3A_INTRODUCTION). I am on Ubuntu 19.04, using `perlbrew` with `perl` version 5.28.1. I installed `RPerl` using:

```
$ cpanm RPerl
```

Then I tried to compile the above program:

```
$ rperl -D p.pl
[...]
[[[ SUBCOMPILE STDERR ]]]

/bin/ld: cannot find -lperl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

ERROR ECOCOSU04, COMPILER, SUBCOMPILE: C++ compiler returned error code,
[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `rperl` needs to link against `libperl.so`, but the `perl` I installed `rperl` with was not built with a shared library `libperl.so`. The solution was to install a new `perl` using configure option `-Duseshrplib`:

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.30.0 --notest --noman --as=5.30.0-reloc -Duseshrplib
$ perbrew use 5.30.0-reloc
$ cpanm RPerl
$ rperl -V p.pl
[...]
$ ./p
Hello Perl
```